# ASP.NET application - Debugging Steps to take

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-6, visual-studio-debugging

An application I developed completely crashes about 2 times a week. When it crashes it takes down the entire application until the Application Pool is Recycled. I can not reproduce the error in the development environment.

Below I have pasted the code that causes the crash and the error message from the application event viewer. **The line that crashes the app starts with ~~~~**. The message states that I have an open DataReader but I checked my code and I always close my data reader and connection.

I don't know what steps I should take to solve this bug. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
 public bool open() {
        //-- check if connection is closed
        if (this.dbconn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) {
            try {
                this.dbconn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                this.errorCode = (int)DatabaseErrorType.DBOpenFailed;
                this.errorMessage = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

/// <summary> closes connection object</summary>
    public bool close() {
        if (!(this.dbconn == null)) {
            if (!(this.dbconn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
                try {
                    this.dbconn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    this.errorCode = (int)DatabaseErrorType.DBCloseFailed;
                    this.errorMessage = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
        // GET MULTI Accounts
    public List<DTO.DTOAccount> GetAccounts(DTO.DTOAccount objAcc) {
        //-- reset error variables
        resetError();

        // make sure the connection is open
        if (this.open()) {

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

            try {

                SqlCommand sqlProcedure = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_Select_ONECARD_ACCOUNTS]", this.dbconn);
                sqlProcedure.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACCOUNT"             , objAcc.AccountId));
                sqlProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UDEF_4"              , objAcc.UDEF_4));

                ~~~~sqlReader = sqlProcedure.ExecuteReader();

                List<DTO.DTOAccount> Accounts = new List<DTO.DTOAccount>();
                // iterate through all values returned
                while (sqlReader.Read()) {
                    DTO.DTOAccount tmpAccount               = new ca.eyecode.onecard.DTO.DTOAccount();
                    tmpAccount.AccountId                    = (String)sqlReader["ACCOUNT"];
                    tmpAccount.Category                     = (String)sqlReader["CATEGORY"];
                    tmpAccount.Groups                       = (String)sqlReader["GROUPS"];
                    tmpAccount.Suffix                       = (String)sqlReader["SUFFIX"];
                    tmpAccount.UDEF_1                       = ((String)sqlReader["UDEF_1"]).Trim();
                    tmpAccount.UDEF_4                       = ((String)sqlReader["UDEF_4"]).Trim();
                    tmpAccount.FirstName                    = ((String)sqlReader["FNAME"]).Trim();
                    tmpAccount.LastName                     = ((String)sqlReader["LNAME"]).Trim();
                    tmpAccount.Picture                      = (sqlReader["PICTURE"] == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (String)sqlReader["PICTURE"]).Trim();
                    // add account items
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.ONEcardCash, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_1"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.Department, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_2"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.BookStore, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_3"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.TechBalance, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_4"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.Bonus1, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_5"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.MealPlanExtra, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_6"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.MealPlanDollars, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_7"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.AramarkCredit, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_8"])});
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add (new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account= AccountType.AramarkEmployees, Balance= Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_9"])});
                    // Combine Totals to One Meal PLAN
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems[5].Balance += tmpAccount.AccountItems[6].Balance;
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems[5].Balance += tmpAccount.AccountItems[8].Balance;
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems[6].Balance = 0;
                    tmpAccount.AccountItems[8].Balance = 0;

                    Accounts.Add(tmpAccount);
                }
                return Accounts;
            }
            finally {
                try {
                if (sqlReader != null)  {
                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
                }
                catch {}
                this.close();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

ERROR

```
 Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 4/19/2012 11:30:39 AM 
Event time (UTC): 4/19/2012 5:30:39 PM 
Event ID: 7715c17b872240829c3dfb562268998e 
Event sequence: 1253 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/997719702/Root-1-129793277036652335 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: 
    Machine name: 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 820 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.DAO.DAOAccount.GetAccounts(DTOAccount objAcc) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\DAO\DAOAccount.cs:line 47
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLAccount.AccountsGet(DTOAccount objAcc) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLAccount.cs:line 228
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLAccount.AccountLogin(String CCID, String Password) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLAccount.cs:line 171
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLFacade.AccountLogin(String CCID, String Password) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLFacade.cs:line 36
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String inpCCID, String inpPASS) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 77
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 9 
    Thread account name:  
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.DAO.DAOAccount.GetAccounts(DTOAccount objAcc) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\DAO\DAOAccount.cs:line 47
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLAccount.AccountsGet(DTOAccount objAcc) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLAccount.cs:line 228
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLAccount.AccountLogin(String CCID, String Password) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLAccount.cs:line 171
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.BL.BLFacade.AccountLogin(String CCID, String Password) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Models\ca.eyecode\onecard\BL\BLFacade.cs:line 36
   at ca.eyecode.onecard.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String inpCCID, String inpPASS) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ONEcard\OneAccount\OneAccount\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 77
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Why aren't you catching the exception?

Comment: if this is crashing the entire site, I'd at least try eating the exception and sending the user to an error page to see if that prevents the site crash.  Then I'd focus on the underlying issue.

Comment: Hi, I not catch the error but I close the reader in the finally block

Comment: Jason good point about sending an error back but that doesn't explain why it crashes the entire site.

Comment: @Victor; there is one anomaly in your code:  notice in the `finally` block, you `try`-`catch` and drop the exception; maybe there is a relevant error happening there that keeps `sqlReader` open until the next call to `GetAccounts()` that THEN causes the "already open" exception.

Comment: The issue was that I had a try finally block in my code. This is a problem because in some cases the finally will not be called. To make sure the finally block is executed every time you can not omit the catch block. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had a try finally block in my code. Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up.

To make sure the finally block is executed every time you can not omit the catch block. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To be sure, you can just start using a `using` statement around your `SqlDataReader`. Do the same for the other elements. That way you're sure they're always being disposed and closed.

Next to that, make sure you don't nest SqlDataReaders. Close them as soon as you can, and do your data access sequential. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need the connection object elsewhere then I'd refactor the method to something like:

```
public List<DTO.DTOAccount> GetAccounts(DTO.DTOAccount objAcc)
{
    //-- reset error variables
    resetError();

    List<DTO.DTOAccount> Accounts = new List<DTO.DTOAccount>();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlProcedure = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_Select_ONECARD_ACCOUNTS]", dbconn))
            {
                sqlProcedure.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACCOUNT", objAcc.AccountId));
                sqlProcedure.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UDEF_4", objAcc.UDEF_4));
                dbconn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlProcedure.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        DTO.DTOAccount tmpAccount = new ca.eyecode.onecard.DTO.DTOAccount();
                        tmpAccount.AccountId = (String)sqlReader["ACCOUNT"];
                        tmpAccount.Category = (String)sqlReader["CATEGORY"];
                        tmpAccount.Groups = (String)sqlReader["GROUPS"];
                        tmpAccount.Suffix = (String)sqlReader["SUFFIX"];
                        tmpAccount.UDEF_1 = ((String)sqlReader["UDEF_1"]).Trim();
                        tmpAccount.UDEF_4 = ((String)sqlReader["UDEF_4"]).Trim();
                        tmpAccount.FirstName = ((String)sqlReader["FNAME"]).Trim();
                        tmpAccount.LastName = ((String)sqlReader["LNAME"]).Trim();
                        tmpAccount.Picture = (sqlReader["PICTURE"] == DBNull.Value ? String.Empty : (String)sqlReader["PICTURE"]).Trim();
                        // add account items
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.ONEcardCash, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_1"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.Department, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_2"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.BookStore, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_3"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.TechBalance, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_4"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.Bonus1, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_5"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.MealPlanExtra, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_6"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.MealPlanDollars, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_7"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.AramarkCredit, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_8"]) });
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems.Add(new DTO.DTOAccountItem() { Account = AccountType.AramarkEmployees, Balance = Convert.ToDouble((Decimal)sqlReader["BALANCE_9"]) });
                        // Combine Totals to One Meal PLAN
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems[5].Balance += tmpAccount.AccountItems[6].Balance;
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems[5].Balance += tmpAccount.AccountItems[8].Balance;
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems[6].Balance = 0;
                        tmpAccount.AccountItems[8].Balance = 0;

                        Accounts.Add(tmpAccount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do some error handling.
    }

    return Accounts;
}
```